# Chrome DevTools Workspaces: is it possible to change the background color?

Tags: ide, google-chrome-devtools

I just read this pretty cool article about Chrome DevTools Workspaces:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/+GoogleChromeDevelopers/posts/644qQuBKZeL

I use black themes for all my coding and believe that it's definitely easier on my eyes. Is it possible -- even as a total hack -- to change the bg color of the DevTools UI?

Even changing the bg color of the open file -- and only that -- would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure look here for tutorial and themes:

https://plus.google.com/115133653231679625609/posts/UZF34wPJXsL

Basically you have to locate the `User Stylesheets` directory and override the `Custom.css` with the given theme:

**Mac:** `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css`

**PC:** `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css`

**Ubuntu (Chromium):** `~/.config/chromium/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css`

Answer (score 0):

As of v.33 of Chrome, the user stylesheets method of [injecting stylesheets no longer works](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=318566).

You can still [create your own themes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21210882/1876861) using the devtools extension method.

But if you just want to download other themes, there's a handful of [themes available at the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/devtools%20theme).