# Issue with Chrome Developer Tool Theme

Tags: google-chrome

I get an issue with the chrome inspector, I recently updated the Custom.css file in order to change the Google Inspector theme but it doesn't work and it seems like my default theme also don't work...

Screen : http://glui.me/?i=y5f88idqnpzmofa/2014-02-05_at_16.10_2x.png/

**EDIT #1**

Screen : http://glui.me/?i=2qai1u5g2xpb3wo/2014-02-05_at_17.29_2x.png/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom.css stop to work in 32.0.1700.76 m Google Chrome update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207474/custom-css-stop-to-work-in-32-0-1700-76-m-google-chrome-update)

Comment: It doesn't work with these methods...

Comment: Define "doesn't work.". The examples in that answer have been tested and are known to work as intended for Chrome 32+ and Chrome 33+.

Comment: I have the version 32.0.1700.107 but when I upload the following package, I don't get an error message but nothing happens and my Custom.css doesn't work...

Comment: *upload*? Nothing in the answer makes any mention of an "upload". Just create a directory, put the files as defined in the answer in your directory, and load the extension in Chrome. Then you're ready to go.

Comment: "Load" sorry... When I load the directory, nothing happens...

Comment: Did you close and re-open the developer tools?

Comment: Yes, I closed ans restarted Chrome...

Comment: Does your Custom.css have a syntax error? Replace everything with `* {background:red !important;}` and see if the devtools turn red. If it doesn't please double-check whether you've followed every step from the answer. If everything fails, zip the extension and mail it to me (contact details at my profile).

Comment: See edit, the devtools turn red... So I think I have a syntax error in my Custom.css...