# Emulation answer of Custom.css for 32.0.1700.76 Google Chrome not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This is in reference to:
[Custom.css has stopped working in 32.0.1700.76 m Google Chrome update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207474/custom-css-stop-to-work-in-32-0-1700-76-m-google-chrome-update)

Posting a new question b/c the system doesn't let me comment on the answer b/c I don't have enough rep points --

The first method doesn't work on Chrome 32.0.1700.107, on either OSes OSX 10.9.1 and Windows 7 SP1.
Followed instructions, created directory, files, etc, added it as chrome extension. Styles are all still the default white

Anyone got this working?

Comment: i'm having this problem too on version 32.0.1700.107