# How to apply styling to panel, created with chrome.devtools.panel.create in your own chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build chrome extension, which adds it's own panel into developer tools. Here is the code, responsible for that (coffeescript):

`devtools.js`:

```coffeescript
chrome.devtools.panels.create 'Panel',
  null,
  'panel.html',
  (panel) ->
    panel.onShown.addListener (win) ->
      container = document.createElement 'div'
      win.document.body.appendChild container
```

Here is `manifest.json` line, responsible for devtools:

```
"devtools_page": "devtools.html"
```

And this is what I have in `devtools.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="devtools.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="devtools.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`devtools.css`:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
}
```

But the problem is I can't make that styles from `devtools.css` apply to my `devtools.html` page.

So, the question is **how can I apply styling to my devtools panel?**

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207474/custom-css-has-stopped-working-in-32-0-1700-76-m-google-chrome-update